# CKEDITOR not defined by my Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, greasemonkey

I'm using Greasemonkey to replace a KTML editor with *CKEditor*.

I first get rid of KTML, then I load jQuery and then *ckeditor.js* and that works, apparently.
But, when I go to replace the `<textarea>`, Firebug reports `"CKEDITOR is not defined"` and my textarea stays normal. Am I loading them in the wrong order?

I ***can*** replace it -- after the page loads -- by entering `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');` in the Firebug console. So CKEditor must have been loaded by Greasemonkey.?.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that the browser didn't finish loading (and thus didn't parse) the CKEditor js file at the time you're trying the `.replace`.

Comment: I tried making the script wait for up to 1.5 seconds, but even that doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the textarea and the script that executes the 'replace'
via ajax?

Try this:

```
parent.CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

or

```
top.document.CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a site I'd built using CodeIgniter. The "CKEDITOR is not defined" just means that it can't find the js file. In my case I'd just edited the .htaccess url rewrite, which broke the path.

So, if you've not fixed this in the intervening 16 months, check your file paths.

Comment: This does not apply to a Greasemonkey application, which has no server-side control of the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `.htaccess` from ckeditor folder. Maybe, if your server is IIS this is problem.

For me, it worked!

Comment: This does not apply to a Greasemonkey application, which has no server-side control of the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
window.onload = function()
{CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );};
```

which was the default on mine, try this

```
$(function()
{CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );});
```